# Duración mm:ss en google sheet

Tags: date, google-hoja-de-cálculo, formato

En Google Hojas de cálculo, quiero poner una celda con duraciones del tipo mm:ss (minutos y segundos). No obstante, en los formatos de hora, fecha y duración no aparecen formatos que no contengan las horas.

Éste es el código que me aparece en el formato estándar
0:04:37
Si escribo un formato personalizado con "minutos transcurridos" y "segundos transcurridos", al escribir 4:37 lo convierte a ::2770

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo utilizar duraciones sin tener que escribir las horas (siempre van a ser cero, en mi caso?

Answer (score 0):

Tú puedes dar el formato que quieras yendo a **`Formato > Número > Fecha y hora personalizadas`**.

Una vez allí, tendrás un modal parecido a este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pulsando sobre la flecha que apunta hacia abajo (círculo rojo) vas a elegir los elementos que necesites en su orden.

1. Eliges **Minutos trascurridos**
2. Escribes **a mano `:`**
3. Eliges **Segundo**

La cosa quedaría así (observa que hay dos puntos entre cada elemento, y esos dos puntos **se escriben a mano**).

Luego pulsas en **`Aplicar`**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Al escribir valores como `0:4:27` o similares en la celda, se formateará del modo esperado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]